# Rich Text Box in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, richtextbox

I am currently porting my application from WPF to Cross-platform. In the WPF, I used a read-only richtextbox to show the result to user in order to show both IMAGE & TEXT. In Xamarin.Forms, Is there anything similar? Thanks.

Comment: Rich-text? Or is HTML an option as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView can be used like readonly richtextbox. I added the elements programmatically(label for text and image). It's also read-only so it met my requirements

Answer (score 4):

There is no control in Xamarin Forms, hence you would have to use CustomRenderers and create your own.

However I only found one decent RichTextBox implementation in

[UWP RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/rich-edit-box)

This means that the only way to get any decent RichTextEditor, is to use a WebView, and load a WebBased rich text editor.

But since you want it as read-only, the simplest thing to do, is to scrap the idea of any RichTextBox, and just display the text and image as separate components in your mobile app.

You can use Spans, in a label to implement formatting within the label if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the **Telerik RichTextEditor for Xamarin** a much better Rich Text Editor package for Xamarin Forms after trying out and evaluating a handful of other alternatives.

This is **licensed software** and you **have to pay** for using it.

**Here's the link,** https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/richtexteditor/richtexteditor-overview

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion's brand-new rich text editor control for Xamarin.Forms is available now. Check out the following article for more detail.

https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/introducing-xamarin-forms-rich-text-editor.aspx